# Add UIView to Application at runtime

Tags: cocoa-touch

I should add a UIView to an application, I use:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[window addSubview:view];
```

But it only work on SpringBoard. Have anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code and it will work. If it doesn't, `view` might be `nil` or the view's `frame` might not be set correctly.

Normally, you would use a view controller and, rather than adding views directly to the window, you would add them to the view controller's view.

Comment: It works only in homescreen with the visible icons, is as if it stay behind the application